# spyder profiler uses wrong python

Tags: python-2.7, profiler, spyder

I am using a virtualenv, but I would like to use an IDE. So I pull up spyder and easily I can change the python interpreter to .virtualenv/myenv/.../python

But, when I go to "F10" for to profile my code, Spyder identifies the interpreter in usr/lib/. I couldn't find anywhere in preferences to change this.

How can I make profiler see the correct python interpreter?

-Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm it seems like this is a bug, can you post it in the Spyder issue tracker?

You can post an issue from within Spyder itself in the help menu click on "Report issue

Comment: Done. You can see the issue here:
https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=2209&thanks=2209&ts=1429797280

Comment: Sorry, that is not our issue tracker anymore. Our current tracker is at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues. As @goanpeca mentioned, this really seems like a bug, so we'll be glad to fix it :-)